# Windows 10 is ignoring my pagefile settings and is unwilling to create or use a pagefile on a different drive

Tags: windows-10, pagefile

Recently, my system performance has been impacted by constant read/writes to the pagefile on `C:` [SSD], so I decided to move the pagefile to `D:` [HDD]; however, when I adjusted the pagefile settings for `C:` to *No Pagefile*, a *Custom Size* of 1024MB~4096MB for `D:`, and restarted, I received error:

```
Windows created a temporary paging file on your computer because of a problem that occurred with your paging file configuration when you started your computer.
```

- When I checked, `C:\pagefile.sys` was 16GB, with no pagefile on `D:`, so I changed my settings again to a *Custom Size* of 16MB for `C:`, and left the settings for `D:` untouched; after rebooting and using the computer for some time, I began receiving out of memory errors, as a pagefile still did not exist on `D:`, even though I configured the settings to create one.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I've seen it before. For some reason windows can't create the page file. Can be a rights issue or anything and ignores that drive completely. If no pagefile is setup anywhere else, it will defaults back to c. The eventlog will give you more information on why the pagefile could not be made on D. In my case it was a weird incompatibility with that specific harddrive/filesystem.

Comment: I'm only asking because I've seen this be the cause about a million times..... when you set the size of the pagefile on D, did you make sure to hit the "set" button before clicking OK?

Comment: Have you tried allowing Windows to control the size of the file, sometimes that helps.

Comment: AFAIK Page files are _per partition_ and therefore do not operate in the way you're thinking, as `C:\pagefile.sys` is for `C:`, `D:\pagefile.sys` is for `D:`, etc. - AFAIK a pagefile can only be used by the partition it's on.

Answer (score 0):

This got to do with some protection enforced by Microsoft on the virtual machine [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2018/20180814-hyper-v-hyperclear-mitigation-for-l1-terminal-fault):

Run as admin, then reboot, and you will be able to use Virtual Memory on drives other than `C:`:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorschedulertype core
```

Comment: The article you linked to contains nothing about why using a hypervisor scheduler type of "core" will solve the problem.  What is the connection?